# Why are RijndaelManaged and AesCryptoServiceProvider returning different results?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rijndaelmanaged, aescryptoserviceprovider

Here is the example that I have run.  It has the same Mode, Padding, BlockSize, KeySize.  I am using the same init vector, key and data.

Using the RijndaelManaged produces an encrypted value of:
0x8d,0x81,0x27,0xc6,0x3c,0xe2,0x53,0x2f,0x35,0x78,0x90,0xc2,0x2e,0x3b,0x8a,0x61,
0x41,0x47,0xd6,0xd0,0xff,0x92,0x72,0x3d,0xc6,0x16,0x2b,0xd8,0xb5,0xd9,0x12,0x85

Using the AesCryptoServiceProvider produces an encrypted value of:
0x8d,0x9f,0x6e,0x99,0xe9,0x54,0x8b,0x12,0xa9,0x88,0x1a,0x3d,0x65,0x23,0x9c,0x4e,
0x18,0x5a,0x89,0x31,0xf5,0x75,0xc5,0x9e,0x0d,0x43,0xe9,0x86,0xd4,0xf3,0x64,0x3a

Here is the code I used to generate these results

```
   public partial class AesTest
   {
      private SymmetricAlgorithm mEncryptionType;
      private byte[] mPrivateKey;
      private byte[] mInitializationVector;
      private byte[] mData;

      public AesTest()
      {
         mPrivateKey = new byte[32] 
         { 
            0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 
            0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 
            0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 
            0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22,
            0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 
            0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 
            0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 
            0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22
         };

         mInitializationVector = new byte[16]
         { 
            0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33,
            0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33,
            0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33,
            0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33
         };

         mData = new byte[16]
         {
            0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44,
            0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44,
            0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44,
            0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44
         };

         mEncryptionType = new RijndaelManaged();
         mEncryptionType.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
         mEncryptionType.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
         mEncryptionType.BlockSize = 128;
         mEncryptionType.KeySize = 256;

         byte[] rij_encrypted_data = Encrypt(mData);

         mEncryptionType = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
         mEncryptionType.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
         mEncryptionType.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
         mEncryptionType.BlockSize = 128;
         mEncryptionType.KeySize = 256;

         byte[] aes_encrypted_data = Encrypt(mData);
      }

      public virtual byte[] Encrypt(byte[] unencryptedData)
      {
         return TransformData(unencryptedData, mEncryptionType.CreateEncryptor(mPrivateKey, mInitializationVector));
      }

      private byte[] TransformData(byte[] dataToTransform, ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform)
      {
         byte[] result = new byte[0];
         if (dataToTransform != null && cryptoTransform != null && dataToTransform.Length > 0)
         {
            // Create the memory stream to store the results
            MemoryStream mem_stream = new MemoryStream();
            // Create the crypto stream to do the transformation
            CryptoStream crypto_stream = new CryptoStream(mem_stream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            // bytes are transformed on a write
            crypto_stream.Write(dataToTransform, 0, dataToTransform.Length);
            // Flush the final block
            crypto_stream.FlushFinalBlock();
            // Convert the transformed memory stream back to a byte array
            result = mem_stream.ToArray();
            // Close the streams
            mem_stream.Close();
            crypto_stream.Close();
         }
         return result;
      }
   }
```

I guess I'm just wondering if I missed something.

**Update:**  Turns out that [AesManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) will throw a CryptographicException ("The specified cipher mode is not valid for this algorithm") if you try and set the CipherMode to CFB.  I feel that the [AesCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx) should do that same, but it doesnt.  Seems funny that the FIPS Certified class allows invalid cipher modes.

Comment: This question came out of discussion of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939040/when-will-c-aes-algorithm-be-fips-compliant

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Response from Microsoft:

`RijndaelManaged` class and
 `AesCryptoServiceProvider` class are two
 different implementations.
 `RijndaelManaged` class is a kind of
 implementation of Rijndael algorithm
 in .net framework, which was not
 validated under NIST (National
 Institute of Standards and Technology)
 Cryptographic Module Validation
 Program (CMVP).

However,
 `AesCryptoServiceProvider` class calls
 the Windows Crypto API, which uses
 RSAENH.DLL, and has been validated by
 NIST in CMVP. Although Rijndael
 algorithm was the winner of the NIST
 competition to select the algorithm
 that would become AES, there are some
 differences between Rijndael and
 official AES. Therefore,
 RijndaelManaged class and
 `AesCryptoServiceProvider` class have
 subtle differences on implementation.

In addition, `RijndaelManaged` class
 cannot provide an equivalent
 implementation with AES. There is
 another class implemented in .net
 framework, `AesManaged` class. This
 class just wrapped `RijndaelManaged`
 class with a fixed block size and
 iteration count to achieve the AES
 standard. However, it does not support
 the feedback size, especially, when
 the mode is set as CFB or OFB, the
 `CryptographicException` will be thrown.

For more information, please refer to
 the following MSDN documents.

[AesManaged Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx)        and [AesManaged.Mode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.mode.aspx)

If you want to pick up standard AES as
 security algorithm in your
 application, we recommend using the
 `AesCryptoServiceProvider` class. If you
 want to mix the `RijndaelManged` class
 and `AesCryptoServiceProvider` class in
 your application, we suggest using CBC
 mode instead of CFB mode in your
 program, since the implementation of
 the CBC mode in both classes is the
 same.

Answer (score 7):

I think it has to do with the CipherMode.CFB. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2007/01/17/new-crypto-algorithms-in-orcas.aspx) describing [AesManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx):

> AesManaged is actually just a wrapper
>   around RinjdaelManaged with some code
>   added to make sure that you do not
>   setup the algorithm to operate in a
>   non-AES compatible way.  For instance,
>   AesManaged does not allow you to
>   change the block size.  (It will also
>   disallow the use of CFB and OFB mode
>   because of the way that
>   RijndaelManaged works with those
>   modes).

Note that if you use CipherMode.ECB or CipherMode.CBC, you'll see identical results. Any reason why you need CFB and not CBC?

Comment: Yeah, VHDL algorithm we purchased to interface with the software only supports the CFB mode.

Comment: I assume AesCryptoServiceProvider is the one that works with your client?

Comment: Yeah, as per the other discussion, it is the FIPS compliant version which is what the customer wants

Answer (score 2):

Addition information from [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2006/10/09/The-Differences-Between-Rijndael-and-AES.aspx) says:

> Essentially, if you want to use RijndaelManaged as AES you need to make sure that:
> 1) The block size is set to 128 bits 
> 2) You are not using CFB mode, or if you are the feedback size is also 128 bits

Ok, great.  I added mEncryptionType.FeedbackSize = 128; to my above example and I get an CryptographicExecption:

> ```
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled
>   Message="Bad Data.\r\n"
>   Source="System.Core"
>   StackTrace:
>        at System.Security.Cryptography.CapiNative.SetKeyParameter(SafeCapiKeyHandle key, KeyParameter parameter, Byte[] value)
>        at System.Security.Cryptography.CapiNative.SetKeyParameter(SafeCapiKeyHandle key, KeyParameter parameter, Int32 value)
>        at System.Security.Cryptography.CapiSymmetricAlgorithm.SetupKey(SafeCapiKeyHandle key, Byte[] iv, CipherMode cipherMode, Int32 feedbackSize)
>        at System.Security.Cryptography.CapiSymmetricAlgorithm..ctor(Int32 blockSize, Int32 feedbackSize, SafeCspHandle provider, SafeCapiKeyHandle key, Byte[] iv, CipherMode cipherMode, PaddingMode paddingMode, EncryptionMode encryptionMode)
>        at System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(SafeCapiKeyHandle key, Byte[] iv)
>        at System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(Byte[] key, Byte[] iv)
>        at AESTest.Form1.Encrypt(Byte[] unencryptedData) in C:\Documents and Settings\nschoonmaker\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\AESTest\AESTest\Form1.cs:line 79
>        at AESTest.Form1..ctor() in C:\Documents and Settings\nschoonmaker\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\AESTest\AESTest\Form1.cs:line 73
>        at AESTest.Program.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\nschoonmaker\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\AESTest\AESTest\Program.cs:line 17
> ```

Is there something wrong with the System.Core dll that wouldnt support this, or do I need to change something else?

On a side note, if I change the FeedbackSize to 8 for both, its seems to work! Even for CFB mode.  So I guess my next question is, how do I get 128 to work (and hopefully this will put an end to this question)?

Comment: Wish I could, the VHDL algorithm again only seems to support 128 for the FeedbackSize :(

Comment: Maybe the FeedbackSize is expressed in bytes, not bits.  8*16 = 128.

Comment: The documentation says its in bits, but hey, maybe its wrong ;)

Comment: It's still bits. FeedbackSize is how many bits the internal feedback register shifts per xor with the input.