# When would I choose AesCryptoServiceProvider over AesManaged or RijndaelManaged?

Tags: .net, aes, rijndaelmanaged

I think the distinguishing factors are

- AesCryptoServiceProvider is FIPS compliant
- AesManaged is cross-platform, requires .NET 3.0
- RijndaelManaged runs on .NET 2.0, requires restricting the blocksize

is that about right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are RijndaelManaged and AesCryptoServiceProvider returning different results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957388/why-are-rijndaelmanaged-and-aescryptoserviceprovider-returning-different-results)

Answer (score 3):

[AesManaged documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) states that

"The AES algorithm is essentially the Rijndael symmetric algorithm with a fixed block size and iteration count. This class functions the same way as the RijndaelManaged class but limits blocks to 128 bits and **does not allow feedback modes.**"

That would suggest its using ECB (Electronic Codebook) mode. This can be a significant weakness to the encrypted data as it means identical blocks of plain text data will result in identical blocks of cipher output.

---

**Edit:** (As correction)
Documentation for the [Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.mode.aspx) property indicates that Mode infact defaults to CBC (which confusingly IS a feedback mode) but cannot be set to CFB or OFB (Cipher Feedback / Output Feedback)

Comment: No - it does not suggest to me that it is only useful for ECB.  Knowing the Microsoft doc style, if in fact AES were usable only for ECBB, the doc state it explicitly. (and it's not "Cookbook", its "Codebook").  There are other modes supported by AES, including CBC.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right, it may be a contradiction in the documentation. Updated answer