# AesCryptoServiceProvider alternate in .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

What id the alternate of AesCryptoServiceProvider (that existed in system.Core -.net 4-) in .net 2.0??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .Net 2.0 you would use the RijndaelManaged class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx

Comment: is it behave the same behavior exactly??

Comment: Well, yes and no.  Yes, it's a standard implementation of the AES crypto algorithm and therefore should produce the same result... and No, it's not the same code because AFAIK it's not FIPS certified.

Comment: No they aren't the same.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4863924/328397