# Decrypting the AES password in C#, which is encrptyed in Python

Tags: c#, python, encryption, aes

I have a encrypted password , which is encrypted in python. It is encrtypted using the base 64 encoded result of the AES 128 encryption with a fixed key.

Now my application is a C# application and I am decrypting it using RijndaelManaged. My code is

```
static String Decrypt(string textToDecrypt, string key)
{
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80; //128 
    rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80; //128
    byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);
    byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10]; //16
    int len = pwdBytes.Length;
    if (len > keyBytes.Length)
    {
        len = keyBytes.Length;
    }
    Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
    rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
    rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;

    byte[] plainText = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);

   return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
}
```

I know how the password is encrtpyed in the python.Its like

```
 key:    encryption key
    s:      string to be encrypted

    cipher            = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    str_to_encrypt    = _create_nonce() + _to_utf16(s)
    encrypted         = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(str_to_encrypt))
```

_create_nonce()  returns some 16 digit value depending on current time.

The issue here is I am getting first 16 as garbage and rest I am getting correctly.
What can be the issue? I think the issue might be rijndaelCipher.IV. How do we calculate the rijndaelCipher.IV when its encrypted in other language?

I am using .Net 2.0 in my application and I can't change that.
Python Code:

```
DEFAULT_KEY = 'SV5@9raQSV5@9raQ'
aes_encrypt(self.DEFAULT_KEY, password)

def _create_nonce():

+    t1 = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
+    t2 = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
+
+    return struct.pack('dd', float(t1), float(t2))
+
+
+def _to_utf16(s, max_len=32, pad='\0'):
+    
+    padded          = str.ljust(str(s), max_len, pad)
+    utf16_padded, _ = codecs.utf_16_be_encode(padded)
+    buffer          = struct.Struct(str(max_len * 2) + 'p')
+    return buffer.pack(utf16_padded)
+
+
+def aes_encrypt(key, s):

+    This will encrypt username and/or password
+    for IP Office Manager application.
+
+    Args:
+
+    key:    encryption key
+    s:      string to be encrypted
+    """
+    cipher            = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
+    str_to_encrypt    = _create_nonce() + _to_utf16(s)
+    encrypted         = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(str_to_encrypt))
+
+    return encrypted
```

Comment: `pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);` is wrong, weak and could very well be part of your problem.

Comment: Seems strange that you encrypt with AES (a specific subset of Rijndael) but are using Rijndael to decrypt. Why not use AesCryptoServiceProvider? It seems like a better fit, and there is less scope for incompatibility. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4863924/14357

Comment: @Henk -  Then what should I do to get pwdBytes?

Comment: @spender - I will check with that

Comment: You do seem to have an IV problem, you'll have to mimic what happens in Phyton. Maybe use a block of 0x00s.

Comment: @HenkHolterman -- I am very new to this. Can you please explain in detail about the 0X00 thing

Comment: You need to post the Python code too.

Comment: @Ben  - I have posted the python code

Comment: Looks like you're using UTF-16 in python, and UTF-8 in C#.

Comment: And why are you using such a crappy encryption scheme in the first place? The way you turn a password into a key sucks. And your nonce generation isn't good either.

Comment: I can't change the encryption logic, its already fixed. If I do like this byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UNICODE.GetBytes(key);, then every thing fails

Comment: And for some reason you're using an IV in C#, but not in python. Also using the key as IV totally misses the point of an IV.

Comment: If the scheme is fixed, tough luck. Tell whoever invented it, to stop inventing his own crypto schemes, because he doesn't know what he's doing.

Comment: *Which* Python AES are you using!!!!! Also please post sample inputs and outputs from python, and the bad output from C#

Comment: Crypto.Cipher import AES.                                                   Encrtyped value o/p of python code: "wDkvBlzgoRCz749u3OjL8/uXXc4CfdEgqP7lk3okP104HxAxQaadVdCWgzE4uUNO9B+RYnstFmDf21C‌ ​SZ89GxnzBJtiirXi0N+/IIocPjwg=" Decrtyped value must be : 16 digit Nonce value + "Administrator" + \0\0\0\0....

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting first 16 as garbage and rest I am getting correctly.

OK, that means you password/key is working but you have a problem with the IV.
You should find out what Python is using, since no IV is visible in the code fragment I guess it could be all zeroes.

```
//rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
rijndaelCipher.IV = new byte[keyBytes.Lenght];  // an array defaults to all 0x00 bytes
```

Comment: By doing that, I am getting everything as garbage. I have posted the python code, can you please have a look

Comment: @Sunil that sounds implausible. Changing the IV in CBC mode decryption does not affect any later blocks.

Comment: Can you please compile the code and tell me issue here. Encrtyped value: 
"wDkvBlzgoRCz749u3OjL8/uXXc4CfdEgqP7lk3okP104HxAxQaadVdCWgzE4uUNO9B+RYnstFmDf21CSZ89GxnzBJtiirXi0N+/IIocPjwg="                                                           Decrtyped value must be  : 16 digit Nonce value + "Administrator" + \0\0\0\0....

Comment: @Ben The choice of  IV only affects all blocks during encryption, but not during decryption. Each block only depends on the cipher text of the previous block. So choosing a wrong IV for decryption only affects the first block.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, in CBC mode the IV affects all blocks. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29. Also using a nonce for the first block is more-or-less equivalent to using an IV - the first block cyphertext is the IV for the second block.

Comment: @CodeInChaos -- In which line it is getting rejected?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, answered question with your help! He doesn't need the first block as the first block only contains the nonce, so it doesn't matter what he puts for IV.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the invalid characters in the base64.

- ***It is working correctly***

  ```
     string textToDecrypt = 
          "wDkvBlzgoRCz749u3OjL8/uXXc4CfdEg"
        + "qP7lk3okP104HxAxQaadVdCWgzE4uUNO"
        + "9B+RYnstFmDf21CSZ89GxnzBJtiirXi0"
        + "N+/IIocPjwg=";
  ```

What you encrypted was nonce+password. What you are getting back is nonce+password.

The first 16 bytes of nonsense you are complaining about ***are the nonce***. Just throw them away.

**Edit:**

As @CodeInChaos pointed out, in CBC mode, if you get the IV wrong, the first block will not decrypt correctly, though the subsequent blocks will. However in your case **the first block is the encrypted nonce**, and you don't care if you get the nonce back or not, since you are going to throw it away anyway. Therefore it does not matter what you use for the IV when decrypting.

Comment: Actually I care for NOnce also. I need that value also :( . Anyway Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

From your question I saw that you said this:

> How do we calculate the rijndaelCipher.IV when its encrypted in other
>   language?

AES is a symmetric cipher. You cannot *(without attempting brute force)* decrypt your cipher WITHOUT the **KEY** and the **IV**.

So, taking from your quote above, you *do not* and *should not* calculate the IV to decrypt. You *must* use the IV that was used when it was encrypted.

You must find out what the phyton code is using for the IV.

Comment: I have posted the python code used for encryption. How to find it?

Comment: Perhaps you need to find out more about the AES library being used. Your code only shows `cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)`. I suggest finding out more about that `AES` class. It could be that it is using a IV of all zeros, which is not secure.

Comment: @Adam an all 0 IV is the least of his problems. The nonce mitigates the lack of IV somewhat, assuming it is really unique(Which it might not be if several strings are encrypted in quick succession).

Comment: Down vote with no comment? *Don't be an anonymous coward.* It is a fact that @Sunil will need the IV used when encrypted in order to decrypt. Whether it be a generated IV or static IV (_including all zeros_)

Comment: @AdamSpicer, that was my downvote, Sunil does not need the IV to decrypt because it is CBC mode and he doesn't need the first block.