# Why are the .NET "Managed" Cryptography classes not permitted if Windows FIPS Compliance policy is enabled?

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, fips

I have been working on making our .NET application FIPS compliant, and have found that the `Managed` Cryptography classes (such as `AESManaged`) are not FIPS compliant. I have read several other articles and questions on which classes are compliant, such as [When will C# AES algorithm be FIPS compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939040/when-will-c-aes-algorithm-be-fips-compliant) and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/e0b4493f-6e20-4b75-a118-6b6e5d26a2a6. It looks like the CryptoServiceProvider classes ARE FIPS compliant, but the Managed classes are not.

I am just wondering if someone can explain the difference between the `CryptoServiceProvider` classes and the `Managed` classes? And if someone can explain why the `CryptoServiceProvider` classes are FIPS compliant, but the Managed classes are not, so I can explain to my boss why I have to rewrite our encryption methods. Are they fundamentally different under the hood? Or has MS just not subjected the Managed classes to NIST certification? If the `Managed` classes just wrap the `CryptoServiceProvider` classes, then why aren't the `Managed` classes automatically FIPS compliant? And if I write a class to wrap a FIPS compliant class into a more easily usable class of my own, is my software no longer FIPS compliant?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.  I was going to post a question about why there were at least 3 implementations in .NET for so many of the different crypto classes but this not only provides "a" reason, if not, "the" reason.  And while I wasn't even thinking about the classes from a FIPS compliance stand-point, knowing this information thanks to your post and Eugene's answer definitely require me to use the CryptoAPI variants -- thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"FIPS-compliant" is wrong term - you are talking about FIPS-certified ones. The difference is that if the algorithm needs to be compatible with reference implementation and third-party implementations, then it needs to be compliant to corresponding FIPS that describes this algorithm. But certification is a different story.

CryptoServiceProvider classes call CryptoAPI (unmanaged Windows API) to perform actual crypto operations, and some CryptoAPI modules are FIPS-certified (for business purposes). Obviously there were not enough reasons to certify .NET managed classes  - if you need certified modules, use CryptoAPI ones. Certification takes lots of time, efforts and significant amount of money.

Also I guess there can be technical reasons that prevent the managed modules from certification, but this is just a guess. It can happen that the nature of .NET (IL and virtual machine) contradict to some requirements defined for certification process, i.e. they just can't be certified.

As for your own wrapper classes - there exist several companies that provide personnel training and certification itself. They also offer consulting services. I hope that somebody from such service responds here, but you can contact them as well if you need.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation helped. I took a look at implementing the CryptoServiceProvider classes and realized the implementation would be exactly the same as the managed classes. It didn't really dawn on me until then what you were saying, that the CryptoAPI classes were just wrapped Windows API code, and that they had passed certification. But the Managed classes were completely written from the ground up in managed .NET code, and since the source was not derivative of the CryptoAPI code in any way, then they must pass their own NIST certification. Makes total sense now. Thanks again.